# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Execution failed for task ':fluttertoast:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':fluttertoast:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s

┌─ Flutter Fix ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                       │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions, then │
│ update F:\Flutter Projects\clima\android\build.gradle:                                       │
│ ext.kotlin_version = ''                                                      │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I am getting such an error when i try to build my flutter project in android studio. Please help someone.

Comment: This link may help you : https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_workmanager/issues/351